# Nginx all subdomain points to one subdomain (gitlab) rule

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I have installed gitlab on my server and use nginx as http server... I simply used recipe for gitlab on nginx

```
# GITLAB
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 3.0

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen 192.168.250.81:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80;
  server_name gitlab.xxx.com;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

gitlab.xxx.com works fine and i get gitlab web documents. But if i want another subdomain i use for Jira (jira.xxx.com) on port 80 (i setup jira on 8080 port normally) gets gitlab web site also.

How can i restrict this rule only serving for gitlab, or may be i can redirect jira.xxx.com to jira.xxx.com:8080

Comment: Where is your `server` block for Jira?

Comment: What do you mean by that ? jira and gitlab are on the same server, gitlab has nginx as server, and jira has apache tomcat. jira runs on 8080 port. but if i dont write down port number in address as http://jira.matriksdata.com , nginz responses and i get gitlab site.

Answer (score 0):

Set up another `server` block, and mark it as `default` in `listen` directive.

Comment: now gitlab is not working

Comment: did you access it by full name, `gitlab.xxx.com`?

Comment: normally yes...